# Can a metal case sitting on a metal desk damage my pc?

Tags: desktop-computer, case, static-discharge, electric-shock, ground

My steel tower case is too tall to fit on the bottom shelf of my metal desk. If I remove the rubber feet it would fit perfectly, but then the bottom of the case would be sitting on the bare metal of desk. If I remove the rubber feet on the case and sit it directly on the metal desk and press the power button, will I fry the pc? Will there be a chance of a static discharge or will I get a nasty shock? What can I do other than putting the feet back on the case to not damage my pc if the case is sitting on metal desk?

Comment: Use any rubber sheet. If you place under the table consider about air circulation also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you feel no electrical shock or tingling from touching either the metal desk or the PC case, then there should be no electrical issue by not having rubber feet.
There should be no reason for the desk to be holding any kind of electrical charge.
As long as the PC is properly constructed, and the case is grounded to earth through a three-conductor power cord and receptacle, then the PC is electrically safe.

If the tower case has any ventilation holes on the bottom, then removing the feet is a bad idea.
If situated on this shelf would restrict air circulation (both intake and exhaust) in any way, then it's a bad location.